# JList placed on form from component palette not responding

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

OK I'm using IntelliJ for a simple sqlite database program.  I'm pretty new to this platform.  I placed a JList component on the form and called it list1.  Now when I try and populate it with strings I used vectors and listmodels but I see no data.  I'm thinking it's not connecting with the JList that was created by IntelliJ.  I've seen examples of doing it all by code, but I would like to know how I can use the JList that is place at design time.  I would like to press a button and populate the list after cycling through the sqlite data.  I know I'm not that good, but here is what I have so far:

```
public class mainForm {
    private JPanel panelMain;
    private JButton button1;
   // private Vector vStatic = new Vector();

/////LOOK HERE ->
    DefaultListModel listModel;
    JList list1;




    public mainForm() {

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

               // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This really sucks!!");
                Connection c;
                Statement stmt;
                listModel = new DefaultListModel();

                try {

                    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:javacarl.db");
                  //  c.setAutoCommit(true);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Open Success!");
                    stmt = c.createStatement();
                    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CARL");
                  //  int i = 0;
                   res.next();

/////LOOK HERE ->
                     while (res.next()) {
                       listModel.addElement(res.getString("JOB"));
                   }
                    JList list1 = new JList(listModel);
                    list1.updateUI();
                    stmt.close();
                    c.close();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Operation Not A Successful!"+e1);
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Operation Success!");

            }
        });

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                new mainForm().createAndShowUI();
            }
        });

        Connection c;
        Statement stmt;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:javacarl.db");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opened database successfully!");
            stmt = c.createStatement();
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CARL " +
                    "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                    " JOB            TEXT    NOT NULL, " +
                    " DATE           TEXT    NOT NULL, " +
                    " MATERIAL       REAL    NOT NULL, " +
                    " LABOR          REAL    NOT NULL, " +
                    " SUBTOTAL       REAL    NOT NULL, " +
                    " TAX            REAL, " +
                    " TOTAL          REAL, " +
                    " DEPAMT         REAL, " +
                    " AMTPAID        REAL)";

            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            stmt.close();
            //  c.commit();
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }

        // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Table Created successfully!" );
    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {

        Toolkit t;
        Dimension s;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MainForm");
        frame.setContentPane(new mainForm().panelMain);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 500));
        t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        s = t.getScreenSize();
        frame.setLocation(s.width / 4 - frame.getWidth() / 2, s.height / 4 - frame.getHeight() / 2);
        initComponents(frame);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }


    private void initComponents(JFrame frame) {
        JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem deleteall = new JMenuItem("Delete all records");
        JMenuItem addjob = new JMenuItem("Add Job");
        JMenuItem exit1 = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        menu1.add(deleteall);
        menu1.add(addjob);
        menu1.add(exit1);

        addjob.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Connection c;
                Statement stmt;

                try {
                    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:javacarl.db");
                    c.setAutoCommit(false);
                    stmt = c.createStatement();
                    //String sql = "DELETE FROM CARL";

                    String sql = "INSERT INTO CARL (JOB,DATE,MATERIAL,LABOR,SUBTOTAL,TAX,TOTAL,DEPAMT,AMTPAID) " +
                         "VALUES ('Disaster on goodrich rd!','03/03/2020', 1000.00, 100.00, 1100.00,11.00,0,0,0 );";
                    //stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                   // sql = "DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name = 'CARL'";
                    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                    c.commit();
                    stmt.close();
                    c.close();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New record failed!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New record inserted!");

                //  JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                //  chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

            }

        });

        deleteall.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Connection c;
                Statement stmt;

                try {
                    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                    c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:javacarl.db");
                    c.setAutoCommit(false);
                    stmt = c.createStatement();
                    String sql = "DELETE FROM CARL";
                    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                    sql = "DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name = 'CARL'";
                    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                    c.commit();
                    stmt.close();
                    c.close();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deletion failed!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All records deleted!");

            }

        });

        exit1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);

            }

        });

        JMenuBar jmb = new JMenuBar();
        jmb.add(menu1);
        frame.setJMenuBar(jmb);
        //  report.addItemListener((ItemListener) this);

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can post this code here that works for me:

```
public void updateJList() {

    Connection c;
    Statement stmt;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:javajobs.db");
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM JOBS ORDER BY ID DESC");
        model.clear();
        while (res.next()) {
            model.addElement(res.getInt("ID") + "*-- " + res.getString("DATE") +"  -- " + res.getString("NAME")
                    + " -- Job Desc: " + res.getString("JOB") + " -- Labor = "
                    + res.getBigDecimal("LABOR")+ " -- Mat = " + res.getString("MATERIAL") + " -- Total = "
                    + res.getBigDecimal("TOTAL"));
        }
        stmt.close();
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Operation JList load Not Successful!" + e1);
    }
}
```